# Zabbix MSSQL Monitoring | MSSQL: Service is unavailable

Tags: database, monitoring, zabbix

```
Zabbix Version 6.4.8
AlmaLinux 8.8 (sapphire carcal)
SQL Server 2008 R2 v. 10.50.1600.1
Using Zabbix template (builtin): MSSQL by ODBC
```

```
odbcinst.ini
[FreeTDS]
Description =  Free Subase & MS SQL Driver
Driver      = /usr/lib64/libtdssodbc.so.0
Setup       = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2
Port        = 1433
FileUsage   = 1
UsageCount  = 1
```

```
odbc.ini
[zabbix]
Driver = FreeTDS
Server = <server IP addr>
PORT = 1433
Database = <db name>
Trace = No
```

```
freetds.conf
[zabbix]
host = <server IP addr>
port = 1433
tds version = 7.4
```

using the above configuration i am able to retrieve all of the triggers: some examples

[Zabbix DB Problem View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0mZo.png)

But for whatever reason the trigger "MSSQL: Service is unavailable" is returning "Service Unavailable"

Trigger expression:

```
last(/MSSQL by ODBC/net.tcp.service[tcp,{HOST.CONN},{$MSSQL.PORT}])=0
```

How do I resolve this issue and why is it returning service unavailable but actually actively retrieving data from the DB itself

Thanks!

Changing Hostname in zabbix frontend
Changing all the configs for odbc and freetds

Comment: is the `{$MSSQL.PORT}` macro correct?

Comment: Yes, and the macro is set to 1433. Also telnet from the zabbix machine connects ok through that port.